# Wary of flattening longish List<String> into String

Tags: java, json, nio

### My situation

1. I have a method that produces a `List<String>`

   - *see [`java.nio.Files.readAllLines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)*
2. I have a different method that requires a `String`

   - *see [`org.json.JSONObject.JSONObject(String)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String))*
3. I want to take the output from *(1)* and put it in *(2)*

### My approach

I'm sorely tempted to just flatten that `List<String>` into one big `String`, but my common sense is tingling. So before I blindly did something like this:

```
List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(""));
String jsonString = "";
for (String s : fileLines) {
    jsonString += s;
}
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I stopped to think and search and ask. One thing I found was that NetBeans suggests the following:

```
List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(""));
String jsonString = fileLines.stream().map((s) -> s)
        .reduce(accountsJsonString, String::concat);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

but my mother always warned me about using code I don't understand. I *think* this is still copying all the data and jamming it together into one big String, so I don't see any practical difference between that and what I originally came up with.

### My question

Is there something wrong with simply gluing all the lines together into one big String, in terms of best practices? Is there a way to achieve my goal of (using `java.nio` and `org.json` in) reading a longish JSON file off disk and into memory that doesn't require duplicating the contents of the file once it's been read in?

### The solution I used

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576412/3802811) to the first (conceptual) half of my question shows there was worse going on than I realized. I've combined [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576405/3802811) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576408/3802811) answers together to address the second (practical) half of my question as follows:

```
BufferedReader jsonReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(...));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(jsonReader));
```

Comment: It's probably wrong.  The `readAllLines` method had to break those strings up for you.  Now you're putting them back together.  Why not just read the file as one single string in the first place?

Comment: Doing this -- `jsonString += s;` -- in a loop is death to the garbage collector.  And I think your second version is doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: @markspace I'd like to have one single string in the first place, but I couldn't see how that was possible. However, it looks like I've got some good answers to peruse now.

Comment: Looks like you may be able to do it directly from the file with a [JSONParser](http://crunchify.com/how-to-read-json-object-from-file-in-java/).

Comment: If you simply *must* concatenate a bunch of Strings, *please* use StringBuilder.  It's much less abusive of the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you want to change the way you're reading the file!

The code you've got at the moment is problematic in terms of the number of dead `String` objects that need garbage collecting (remember that a `String` is immutable, so it's creating a new object each time you add a bit on). It's also got quadratic runtime in the length of the list, because each time it adds something on, it has a longer and longer `String` that it needs to copy.

I think that the functional-style Java 8 code that NetBeans is suggesting is also going to be quadratic: it's going to be using that `concat` repeatedly in its reduce function.

Your other option would be to use a `StringBuffer` or an array of `char`. With the latter, you can loop through the list determining total length, allocate an array accordingly, put things into the array, and then create a big `String` from that. That will give you something linear in the total length, rather than quadratic.

Comment: Accepted since it's the single answer I found the most helpful, especially for the "why-is-this-wrong" part of my question (although they've all been helpful, and this wasn't the solution I used for the second part of my question).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using those methods to construct the JSONObject (it appears that this is your end goal), why not use the methods that were designed to load a JSONObject into memory.

```
Reader fromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
JSONTokener tokens = new JSONTokener(fromFile);
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(tokens);
fromFile.close();
```

Then you get the JSON library you chose to do the work for you :)

This relies on [JSONTokener](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONObject.html) from the same library you specified.

Comment: Aha! The `JSONTokener` never occurred to me, since I had been doing my file loading in a separate class from the `JSONObject` construction. Passing the strings into constructors for my various collection managers allowed them to not know anything about the file I/O, but with the tokener I can also choose to pass around a Reader or InputStream instance, which is still acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-) instead? It seems to me that there is no need to work with the individual lines.

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String jsonString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, note the warning on that method:

> Note that this method is intended for simple cases where it is convenient to read all bytes into a byte array. It is not intended for reading in large files.

So if you are working with a large file, you should probably use a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
```

Comment: Well, OP wants a `JSONObject` built from the entire contents of the file, so it had better be a short enough file to fit comfortably in memory in any case!

Comment: Yes, I saw that warning and shied away. Though at the time I assumed the overhead was the same for my algorithm and this one, but given [chiastic-security's explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25576412/3802811), this assumption was way off. Together with [Strikeskids' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25576405/3802811), yours is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to me, this is a better way to do it:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(""))) {
    pw.println(line);
}
String bigString = sw.toString();
```

This captures the line breaks, etc.

Comment: Nice. +1 for an inside-the-box answer that fixes the biggest problem with the smallest change necessary (even though I'm making larger changes given all I've just learned).